# Error when running Python file from command line

Tags: python-3.x

I can't run the script through the terminal, but let's say everything works as it should in Thonny or PyCharm. There were problems with the asynchronous library, but switching to python 3 solved everything, now it gives the following error:

```
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python  /home/pi/telegram/telethon/tele.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/telegram/telethon/tele.py", line 22, in <module>
    api_id   = config['Telegram']['api_id']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Telegram'`
```

Comment: If you don't provide your code, we are highly unlikely to be able to help.

Comment: [Do read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try running with `python3.7` or `python3.8` depending on your versions on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Your `config` variable doesn't contain `'Telegram'` key. That's why you get this error.

Why? Nobody knows without code that sets this variable. As it is not a library file but your custom code (just with the same name).

You can try to print it and see the actual value.